# Addressing tag scope inconsistencies

Tags: discussion, tags

It feels like the tags on the beta had kicked off extremely inconsistent in the range of scopes. In my experience from other sites, when I ask a question it should be reasonably clear whether I am expected to tag [novels](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novels) or [fantasy](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) or [english-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english-literature) or [20th-century](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/20th-century) or [j-r-r-tolkien](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j-r-r-tolkien) (or [john-ronald-reuel-tolkien](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-ronald-reuel-tolkien)) or [lord-of-the-rings](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings) or [return-of-the-king](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/return-of-the-king) or [gollum](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gollum).

It should be clearly decided **where to draw the line**, and justified exceptions from that should remain exactly that.

It seems that people want to go at least as specific as **authors** or **books / series / universes**, so I would disallow (read: discourage in the tag wiki and start removing from questions) tags any more general than that (form, country, age), with the only exception of questions which *really* address, e.g., [short-stories](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories) or [russian-literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/russian-literature) as a whole (for example, recommendation requests). Of course, there can be two tags of different scope to facilitate filtering, as is usual elsewhere (e.g., [c++](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [move-semantics](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/move-semantics)), but [j-d-salinger](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j-d-salinger) [short-stories](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories) makes no sense at all to me, neither does the sole existence of tags like [prequels](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prequels).

Comment: I think you're mixing different issues and concerns together. There's such a thing as intrinsically bad tags (e.g. meta tags). There's such a thing as misuse of tags (american-literature should be used for analyzing american literature as a whole, not individual works by American writers. Prequels should be tagged only when discussing something related to prequels as a thing, NOT a work that happens to be a prequel). These are all separate issues and should be discussed separately.

Answer (score 2):

As I already said on [a related question](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/89/17):

> **Why not just leave things to grow organically?**
>
> During the private beta, everyone has the ability to create new tags and to suggest tag edits to questions. Let's just allow the tagging system to propagate as it will, and only start making drastic changes if things start to be really problematic (e.g. if a tag like [fiction](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiction) or [spoiler](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoiler) starts being used on dozens of questions).

You have the power to suggest edits to any post. Use it wisely. Suggest retags. Set an example by demonstrating with your own questions how you think tags should be used. A system will shake out in time; just wait for more questions to appear, more edits to be made, and more people to join in.